# dynamic display of 3d DEM using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, dynamic, qgis2threejs, three-js

When I used `QGistoThreejs` plugin in QGIS and run after adding a tif file... the output generated with the files created in the specified location....

Let's say if I name it as `sample.html` when I run the plugin... the following files will be generated with the specified location

1. dat-gui(folder)
2. threejs
3. dat-gui_panel.js
4. Qgis2threejs (css file)
5. Qgis2threejs.js
6. sample.html
7. sample.js

But if I want to change the DEM dynamically to display in HTML page that was created, I observed that we need to change `sample.js` file... (i.e, javascript file with specified name) should be overridden for the DEM selected.

So, is there any way to override that javascript file using web?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to be able to switch between several DEMs in a single exported qgis2threejs page?

Recent versions of qgis2threejs allow multiple rasters using the **Additional DEM** option... see below for suggested settings (the main DEM is under the DEM settings) :-

[image: additional dems dialog]

For best results they need to be aligned and use similar vertical scales, but you can show several rasters.

By default they all display at the same time, but you can go into the layers accordion and turn layers on/off one-by-one.

In this case I have two DEMs, each styled differently. The tall, semi-transparent one is the proximity to sea level pixels. The lower one is the DEM. I can turn off each one separately.

[image: multiple rasters in qgis2threejs]

If you look at the generated sample.js in that case, you'll see how it adds to the layer data.

If you want different behaviour I'm sure that can be done with some additional JavaScript.. hopefully the generated sample.js will give you ideas how to implement this.